# Hiding element in Java Swing inside a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

What you have to know :

- I have a GridBagLayout inside a panel.
- Inside my GridBagLayout I have 4 elements :

  - JLabel title at gridy = 0
  - textfield username at gridy = 1
  - textfield address IP at gridy = 2
  - error message in setVisible(false) at gridy = 3

If I don't touch anything, this is working perfectly well.

But if I setVisible(true) the error message, the whole view moves up. Making me think that the setVisible(false) is not really hiding the item but "removing it from the panel".

How can I hide my item without "removing it from the panel" ?

Comment: A invisible element does not get laid out, or more importantly is "generally" ignored or, if it is laid out, generally produces a size of `0x0` ... which is basically all the same thing

Comment: What we *really* need to know and see is your best attempt at a [mcve] program. Please post this. And myself, I'd put the error message in a JLabel, and not set it invisible. Instead make it visible, give it `"   "` an empty String, and then later a text-filled String.

Comment: Usually in a GUI one uses `setEnabled()` to prevent users from interacting with components.  Though I'm not sure what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What about an empty error message instead of an invisible one?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah, that's a solution but I was hoping that there was a more "clean" way.

Comment: The clean way is to specify a minimum width for your label so what when you set text to it it wont make it bigger and shift other components around.

Comment: @tsolakp I got your point, but whichever elem at whatever width I set, if I setVisible(false) it, and then setVisible(true) it will "pop" in the panel. Let me know if you don't understand me

Comment: As other suggested dont make it invisible at all. It just will be a label without text but wide enough to display text and not shift things around.

Comment: @tsolakp Yeah, but to my opinion this is a dirty way around.

Comment: It is not ugly at all. That is a preferred method over the changing components visibility. If you still want to go with visibility approach then use JPanel with minimum width that will contain your JLabel.

Comment: @tsolakp I disagree with you. Anyway thanks for your help buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setVisible` to show and hide elements. Pretty much only use that method for Frames. You rather want to use a `TabbedPane`, where you don't show the tabs and don't have any borders, and simply switch the tab in your code to a pane which has nothing on it from a pane which has some components.